# Can't handle "(" functions in if

Tags: batch-file

My script:

of course i can't give my whole script

```
set /p answer=
if %answer% == Yes (
set answer=Yes
goto :Success
)
if not %answer% == Yes (
set error=failed
goto :failed
)
```

But when it gets executed, the script doesn't seem to be like that.
My script has a problem of the "(". in the code. How do i fix it?

Comment: Sorry, what's your question? Also, I can pretty much guarantee that your problem lies elsewhere (although you may just need quotes around `%answer%` and `Yes`), but I'm going to need more information before I can say for certain.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost impossible to fix as you have not provided enough of your code. For all we know the section you've provided is within a code block  a and not utilising delayed expansion.

That said, you need to learn not to use `Set/P` when expecting specific answers.

Try changing your submitted section to this structure:

```bat
Choice /M "What is your answer"
If %ErrorLevel%==1 GoTo Success
Set "error=failed"
GoTo :EOF

:Success
```

Once again, due to your lack of information it is difficult to provide you with a more understandable solution with respect to your witheld code.